# How to get path not appear on URL

Tags: url, redirect, html

I have a webpage at `http://novastudios.whostf.com`. I set up a redirect to `http://novastudios.whostf.com/home.html` but I don't want the `/home.html` part to appear on the URL. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to name the page `/index.html`, instead of `/home.html`.  That that way, you could simply put a link to  `http://novastudios.whostf.com`, and the web browser will automatically look for a page called `index.html`.